# HQL query com lista de ENUM como parametro

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hql

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema, segue um exemplo:

Tenho uma entidade `Banda` que possui como atributo uma lista de generos `List<Generos> generos`, `Generos` é um ENUM com os seguintes valores: `ALTERNATIVE_ROCK("Alternative Rock"), CLASSIC_ROCK("Classic Rock"), HARD_ROCK("Hard Rock"), HEAVY_METAL("Heavy Metal"),PROGRESSIVE_ROCK("Progressive Rock");`

Estou tentando criar um método que retorna uma `List<Banda>` passando como parametro uma lista de ENUM `List<Generos>` utilizando HQL... tipo 
`public List<Banda> retornaBandasPorGenero(List<Generos> generos);` porém sem sucesso, qual a melhor maneira de resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o método [setParameterList](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)) ao associar o respectivo parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
Generos[] paramGeneros = {Generos.ALTERNATIVE_ROCK, Generos.CLASSIC_ROCK};
IQuery minhaQuery = sessao.createQuery("from Banda b where b.Genero in (:colecaoGeneros)");
minhaQuery.setParameterList("colecaoGeneros", paramGeneros); // Olha ele aí!
```

Comment: Valeu @Jônatas Hudler!!! funcionou perfeitamente... não tinha conhecimento desse método...